# Numerically stable polynomial coefficients determination

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I have several polynomials $P_j(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n\alpha_{jk}x^k$ and for each of them I have $n+1$ couples $(x_{ji}, y_{ji})$ (such that $y_{ji} = P_j(x_i)$), and I want to find the coefficients vectors $\boldsymbol \alpha_j$. I know that I can use Lagrange interpolation or solving the Vandermonde systems:

$$V(\mathbf x_j)\boldsymbol \alpha_j = \mathbf y_j$$

s.t.

$$V(\mathbf x_j)_{ik} = x_{ji}^k$$

But Lagrange interpolation is not numerically stable and the condition number of my Vandermonde matrix $\kappa(V(\mathbf x_j))$ is somewhere between $10^{13}$ and $10^{17}$ depending on the polynomial $P_j$, which causes problems to my application.

What stable method is available to me for that purpose?

Comment: You might get a slight improvement by changing the monomial basis for the Chebyshev or Bernstein basis polynomials. Also, what is unstable in Lagrange interpolation is the determination of the monomial coefficients, the direct evaluation of the Lagrange basis polynomials (in product form) might also prove slightly more stable.

Comment: I *believe* that the problem is you are insisting on using the standard basis. Use a B-spline basis and things will be much better.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not really an option: I have a matrix series which I simplify into a matrix polynomial by using Cayley-Hamilton theorem. But I need to find the coefficients of that polynomial. So if I change the monomial basis, the coefficients might be easier to compute but they won't equal the coefficients of the matrix polynomial I am looking for.